# Inserting value into a JavaScript file template and generating a new file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a web application with a form and an number of inputs:

```
<form action="">
    Title1:<br>
    <input type="text" name="title1">
    <input type="text" name="title1Description">
    <br>
    Title2:<br>
    <input type="text" name="title2">
    <input type="text" name="title3Description">
    <br>
    Title3:<br>
    <input type="text" name="title3">
    <input type="text" name="title3Description">
    <br>
    <button type="button">Insert an Generate!</button> 
</form>
```

I also have a JavaScript file which acts as a template:

**template.js**

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;
}

function mySecondFunction(p3, p4) {
    return p3 - p4;
}

var myData = {
    *title1* : {
        Title: *title1*,
        Description: *title1Description*
    },
    *title2* : {
        Title: *title2*,
        Description: *title2Description*
    },
}
```

When a user clicks the button, how can i generate a copy of template.js insert the values the user has entered into the *xxxxx* parts of var myData,  and prompt the user to download the newly generate file?

I can use AngularJS if this makes it easier than jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy of template.js" and and what is the user actually supposed to download? The js file?

Comment: By copy, i dont want the template.js file to over overwritten, it should always be a template as many users can/hopefully will use the application. Yes, they should download the new .JS file with the inserted values.

Comment: I understand, see my answer for a possibility to achieve that. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @treegarden - thanks, i've upvoted, but would be nice to see a complete solution on jsFiddle or Plunker.

Comment: Check my comment, I added all the code you need...

Comment: @treegarden - thanks! marked as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write the entire code, but here's what I'm thinking about:

When the button is clicked, you could pass the values e.g. using GET variables. Click [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/) to find out how that works.

Next you can save the entire code of the js file in a String, and use the values from the GET variables.

And last but not least, use the following code to download a file containing the generated String `str`:

```
window.open('data:text/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(str));
```

**Edit**
The solution above doesn't make it possible to store the file with a custom file name. If you want to accomplish that, you would need a little work around, because you need to use the download attribute of `<a>`:

```
var link = document.createElement("a"); 
var csv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + str;
link.setAttribute("href", encodeURI(csv));
link.setAttribute("download", "template.js"); //custom file name here
link.click();
```

Be aware that not every browser supports the download attribute. Check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) to find out more.

**Edit2**
Okay, I wrote the code, because I was having a good day and not much to do ;) You can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/ZCWXNm1V) (jsFiddle was giving me troubles)

Comment: for some reason this only works in Chrome. Just tried in the latest version of Firefox and the download won't initiate.